# contents of a .a static library file

Tags: c, arm

I was shared a static library file('.a' file). When i opened it with 7z, it included two files, one without extension and one with .o extension. What are these files. Is the .o an object file here and which one of these file is actually linked during linking process.

More info about the .a file:
Lets name the file xyz.a:
When i un compress it or view it with 7z, i can see two files:
 - xyz 
 - abc.o

Comment: Do you have the same files when you extract with `ar(1)` (`ar x file.a`) ? Did you use `file(1)` to have more info about this files ?

Answer (score 0):

The '.a' file can contain several '.o' files added by the `ar` utility. It can also contain an index mapping global symbols to the '.o' files that contain them. On some systems (mostly SysV or GNU based), `ar`'s `s` option is used to update the index. On other systems (mostly BSD based), the index is updated by a separate `ranlib` utility.

To answer your questions, the '.o' files are the object (code) files that make up the library, the other file is the index, and some subset of the '.o' files will be linked by the linker, with the assistance of the index to determine which '.o' files are needed.

With the `ld` linker, the option `-l foo` would search for a dynamic library called `libfoo.so` or a static library called `libfoo.a`. Other `ld` options control whether it looks for a static or dynamic library and where to look for it.